# IBM MFP 7.0 Android JSONStore data is NOT being refreshed

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I have a hybrid app running in both iOS and Android and built using MFP 7.0. The app leverages JSONStore to handle data and being synced from our backend system for local processing. Both iOS and Android are using the same source code. In iOS, data are being refreshed when there are new updates from backend but not in Android. Please help which should we check.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without any code how could we even begin to guess?

Comment: Do you see Android trying to sync ? And do you see it getting data? Have you debugged your code to see how far it goes? And do share some code

Comment: Data sync is working fine. When I uninstall the app from device and re-install again, data will be re-synced. Just wondering if there is any new updates in MFP pertaining to Android new version.

Answer (score 0):

When you say uninstall the app, it is same as dropping your data (table).
When you reinstall app,the same data will be re-synced which was dropped previously.